# Replacing mod_plsql with Oracle Rest Data Services

Tags: oracle, mod-plsql

We are in the process of upgrading an application running on Oracle 10g and oracle HTTP server to Oracle 12C.
Due to mod pl/sql being deprecated we have chosen following combination.
 oracle 12c + ORDS 3.0 and tomcat. (we are not using APEX)

A major functionality of our application is uploading files via website to the documents table in the database schema.

While doing that we are getting error "500 Internal Server Error" which has been experienced by others on this link https://community.oracle.com/thread/3891751

If anyone has got a sucessfull file upload into Documents table via Oracle Rest Data Services config I would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I could prove, it is not possible to upload files with ORDS without having APEX installed. You will have to install APEX even if you do not use it in your application.

You can try another gateway but most are deprecated, I have started to develop one in Java without APEX dependencies. When I have it ready I will publish it in github.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the latest ORDS release as explained my own question related to this topic:
[File uploads in a non-Apex PL/SQL application migrated to ORDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748052/file-uploads-in-a-non-apex-pl-sql-application-migrated-to-ords)