# File uploads in a non-Apex PL/SQL application migrated to ORDS

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ords

The official Oracle document 1982130.1 describes the missing feature that currently prevents us from migrating from mod_plsql to ORDS:

> Migrate a Non-Apex PL/SQL application from Oracle HTTP Server to
>   Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) 2.0.9. When running the PL/SQL
>   application with Oracle REST Data Services, got the following error
>   message: "ORA-20888: p_application_id must be provided" error in
>   catalina.out regardless of the value of that parameter.

What are others doing to migrate a non-Apex application from mod-plsql to ORDS?

Comment: upgrade to the latest ords , 17.4. and this was addressed

Comment: @KrisRice Wow, that’s good and surprising news. I wrote this question after the official Oracle support informed me that this problem still persists in the latest version of ORDS. Did you already test it?

Comment: I coded it ;) . I'll get you a longer "answer" in a sec.

Comment: Important question. Do you have apex in this db at all? my answer is different based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORDS 18.3+ the logic changed to make it easier for non-apex.  Here's the new logic in a flow chart hopefully make it easy to follow.

[image]

In Previous to 18.3 and below here's how to accomplish the same >

The catch is right now is there's a hacky workaround to getting this to work and that's to pretend apex is too old to use that code path. ( yeah yeah I'll fix this )

In the db user that is configured in the connection pool file, create this view. The code checks that if apex 4+ is installed to use that. This view is how that is checked so forcing ords to thing apex is old will make the plain 'ol DOC Table path be used.

```
create view apex_release as
  select '1.0.0.0' VERSION_NO from dual;
```

url-mapping.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pool-config xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apex/pool-config">
   <pool base-path="/klrice" name="klrice" />
</pool-config>
```

conf/klrice.xml

The parameter is named apex.docTable and this *will* default to "FLOWS_FILES.WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
  <entry key="db.username">klrice</entry>
  <entry key="db.password">klrice</entry>
  <entry key="apex.docTable">klrice.MYDOCTABLE</entry>
</properties>
```

My Table

```
KLRICE@xe >CREATE TABLE MYDOCTABLE (
  2    NAME               VARCHAR(256)   UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
  3    MIME_TYPE          VARCHAR(128), 
  4    DOC_SIZE           NUMBER, 
  5    DAD_CHARSET        VARCHAR(128), 
  6    LAST_UPDATED       DATE, 
  7    CONTENT_TYPE       VARCHAR(128), 
  8    CONTENT            LONG RAW, 
  9*   BLOB_CONTENT       BLOB );
```

After being called:

```
  1* select BLOB_CONTENT from MYDOCTABLE
KLRICE@xe >/

BLOB_CONTENT                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000C8000000C80806000000AD58AE9E00000001735247
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive feedback and a few more questions: my application does not use apex, but is there a difference between having apex installed or not? What actually changed in the latest version or was this also possible before? Is it actually all about the apex_release view tricking ORDS to believe that there is no apex available?

Comment: It was possible before just as you can see very non obvious.  I’m fixing it this week properly that if a new param owa.docTable is set it does that directly no workarounds.

Comment: So it will be available “soon” in a minor ORDS update?

Comment: Yeah that’s as much as I can say... soon.

Comment: Looking forward to it. Thank you!

Comment: @Kris Rice did owa.docTable get released? I am working on porting a mod_plsql app to ORDS (so far it is working great).  I need to tackle file uploading next.  I am using v18.2.

Comment: Yes in 18.3 this was overhauled to act better. That's coming soon. I'll blog about the changes.